# Remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections error in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I am getting the below error while connecting to yugabyte cloud DB:

```
Error: "Remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections"
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar:42.3.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2787) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar:42.3.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar:42.3.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:290) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar:42.3.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar:42.3.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar:42.3.5]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar:42.3.5]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar:42.3.5]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:159) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means the number of connections from database clients has exceeded the amount of connections that a node is set to be serving. This can be changed using the `-ysql_max_connections` tserver flag. In general, it's good to be conservative with max connections and the number of connections.

For a guide see https://blog.yugabyte.com/database-connection-management/